# Vue.js - Different branding and styles depending on different domains

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, tailwind-css

I need to change the app branding or theme depending on the domain where is hosted using the same codebase,
I'm using vue.js with the vue-cli and tailwindcss for the styling, is there a way to achieve this?

Example: visits a.com, shows blue color theme, visits b.com, shows the same page but with different colors.

Answer (score 1):

You can run in a beforeCreate method in your app.vue to check the host, like this window.location.host, and do your tasks to set your style.

e.g.

```
async beforeCreate() {
    const url = window.location.host; //http://localhost:8080

   if(url === "something.com"){
     doSomething();
   }else{
     doSomethingElse();
   }
}
```